# How does 2015 RR245 compare to the other KBOs predicting "Planet 9"?

Tags: 9th-planet, dwarf-planets, kuiper-belt

2015 RR245 was recently announced, in a highly eccentric orbit in the KBO. From what I understand, the so called "Planet 9" was predicted because these objects tended to be pointed in a particular direction. How is this object pointed relative to the other KBOs?

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It was the first thing I thought too, but I would say it won't count in the statistics.  The earlier [paper by Batygin & Brown](http://arxiv.org/pdf/1601.05438v1.pdf) was talking about bodies orbiting further out.

[2015 RR245 orbits](http://www.minorplanetcenter.net/db_search/show_object?object_id=2015%20RR245) between 33.7 and 129 AU.  The "cluster" of bodies considered in the paper have aphelion distances from 150 AU upwards.  So I think it would be a mistake to try and fit this new body into the existing figures.

Comment: Yes, and this new object is well within Neptune's sphere of influence.